# Yii2 - validate field from model in main.php file

Tags: php, layout, yii2

**I have a table called user, and inside it a field called estatuto.**

Only users with estatuto == admin can see Admin hyperlink in my NavBar widget located in main.php file.

My problem is to check in:

```
'label' => 'Admin', 'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
```

if a user is logged with estatuto == admin, and only in that condition show the admin hyperlink.

I can only check if a user is Guest or not Guest.

I need something like:

```
'label' => 'Admin', 'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest && User::estatuto = 'admin',
```

I searched a lot and the only thing i saw and couldn't understand was through:

```
$this->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
```

But maybe there's another aproach.

**Anyone can help me solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Your task is not about validating model field, it is classical permission management task. So you should use [Yii2 RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac) feature. in that case you can check permission like that:

```
\Yii::$app->user->can('viewAdminMenu')
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of estatuto in session when the user logs in.

Then at any point just call that value from session.

Also don't set the visible tag for access. You need to not show the entire link if not admin.
Also hiding just links is not enough, you need to check for access within the controller as well.

A better way to do this is use Role Based Access Control or RBAC.

Comment: But... when user logs the NavBar must check at once if is admin or not, and how to pass to $SESSION the value of the User::estatuto field?

Comment: Wherever you are using the code to log in the user. When the user logs successfully fetch the value of 'estatuto'  for that user from DB and store in session. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html